# Woocommerce - checkout error after plugin update

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I have recently updated woocommerce plugin in my wordpress site to latest version and now the checkout if not working. Below are the error messages that I am seeing in Chrome and Firefox on checkout page. I am not able to understand if any hack is required to solve this from our end. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Chrome Message-SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

**Firefox Message-SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 6 column 1 of the JSON data**

Comment: Refer to the solution in this topic https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/8763

Answer (score 0):

A little late but better than nothing.
I am using Wordpress 4.4.2 and WooCommerce plugin 2.5.5 and have the same problem when checkout.

Please take a look at this solution: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/json-error-on-checkout-page/page/2#post-8159100.

Summary: Open file checkout.min.js in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend` and put string

> 1!==d["blockUI.isBlocked"]&&c.block

in parenthese like this

> (1!==d["blockUI.isBlocked"]&&c.block)

Answer (score -1):

In Config File write the following code:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Ref:
For more details check the [response and solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/24-common-issue-syntaxerror-unexpected-token?replies=1) from the WooCommerce Author

Comment: I have added above code to wp-config but it did not solve the issue.